# Are all modes available in a non-deluxe version of Star Wars Battlefront?

Tags: star-wars-battlefront-2015

If I buy just a normal version of Star Wars Battlefront (2015), are all blocked modes, and maps of beta version available?

Further, is the Season Pass only for modes yet to be revealed?

Comment: Hi Patrick. It looks like you actually have two questions here. You should split these questions up so that each can get it's own answers. Also, you'll probably want to expand a bit more on what exactly you mean about each of these and add a bit more information and context. Thanks

Comment: Sorry about that @Ktash. I'll split.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Everything in the beta menus are part of the standard edition of the game. That includes the maps, characters, upgrades, game modes, etc.

The future DLCs (included in the season pass and ultimate edition) add new environments. What comes with these environments is a mystery right now. Currently, the Battle of Jakku is the only announced DLC and obviously this will introduce a new map, but it isn't known if this will bring new game modes, characters, or other new features.

<sup>Sources:

1. http://starwars.ea.com/starwars/battlefront/buy

2. http://starwars.ea.com/starwars/battlefront/news/jakku-pre-order-offer</sup>

Answer (score 1):

## Modes

The following [modes are currently available](http://starwars.ea.com/starwars/battlefront/features/game-modes):

- Blast (team deathmatch)
- Cargo (capture the flag)
- Droid Run (king of the hill, with 3 'hills' active)
- Drop Zone (king of the hill, with changing 'hills' dropping randomly on the map)
- Fighter Squadron (team deathmatch, space vehicles only)
- Heroes vs Villians (protect the VIP, with 3 VIPs on each side)
- Hero Hunt (don't bother with this mode until it is fixed)
- Supremacy (control point)
- *Turning Point (specialized assault) [*available to all in the free Battle of Jakku DLC]
- Walker Assault (specialized assault)

The Battle of Jakku DLC offered a new mode after the game's initial release. The mode is called Turning Point, which is a slightly specialized "assault" mode. This DLC and therefore mode is available to all players for free.

It is still unannounced if any of the non-free DLC in the future will contain new modes.

## Maps

Each DLC will include one or more new maps, often with several different variations for whichever modes each map will support. (Maps often only support a handful of modes.) Those new maps will only be available to play by users who own that DLC. (Though the first DLC, Battle of Jakku is free to everyone.)

## Matchmaking

Because there are different modes and map rotations based on which DLC you own, there is a toggle in the top left of the menu to select which map rotation you would like in your matchmaking results. For example, as of the first DLC, the options are "Main Game" and "Battle of Jakku". If you select "Main game" you will be matched to only modes and maps from the initial release. Selecting the DLC rotation will include the initial release modes and maps plus the new ones from that DLC. However, when selecting the DLC option, you will not get matched with users who have Main Game selected, even though you might end up on a map from the main game. (Why? No good reason. Developer laziness?)

It has not been announced how the rotations will work if you own a hodge podge of DLC. Will it be a selection of Main game vs all DLC, Main game vs DLC 1 vs DLC 3, or will they actually make it smart enough to not make you arbitrarily make this selection in the first place? (Obviously it should be the last option, but based on what we've seen so far, that is the least likely one for DICE to implement.) It is currently unknown how DICE will combine or restrict the matchmaking with the subsequent DLC.

Either way, it is DICE; so expect it them to have a simple solution. (Note: not "good"—just "simple".) It won't be flexible and you as a player will have little say in what match you get assigned to besides the two options mentioned above: Mode and Map Rotation.

## Deluxe Edition and Season Pass

The Deluxe Editions gets you extra skins, free Star Card unlocks, and a few other items. There are no extra modes or game play with the Deluxe Edition.

The Season Pass does include new modes and maps, and gets you the first 4 DLC as if you bought them all at once. But it doesn't change which maps or modes you get if you were to purchase the DLC one-by-one.